# How to Validation value with array data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation

**This my HTML Code**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Validation Array</h2>
    <input id="search" onblur="read()">

    <label id="creat"></label>

  </body>
</html>
```

**And this my Javascript**

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

function read() {
  if(search != fruits){
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Error";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Valid";
  }
}
```

i want to validation write "Valid" if value = in array. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems, you need to get the search value within the function, otherwise it will be the first value no matter which changes are made. Then, you can use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the value is in the array.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function read() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  if(!fruits.includes(search)) {
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Error";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Valid";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Validation Array</h2>
    <input id="search" onblur="read()">

    <label id="creat"></label>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.includes()` method:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

function read() {
  if(!fruits.includes(search)){
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Error";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Valid";
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

```js
function read() {
  let inArray = fruits.includes(search);
  if(inArray){
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Error";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("creat").innerHTML = "Valid";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop through all elements and check of the current element is equal to the string entered in "search". Or you can just use the .includes function ;)